# github basic authentication using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, basic-authentication, github-api

I'm trying to login to github from an angular application.  I'm brand new to angular.

I'm using github.js https://github.com/michael/github plugin for the github hooks.

My javascript is below.  I set the module and create an auth controller.  This is triggered by a form in the html.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);   
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = '';
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.auth = function() {
    console.log($scope.username);
    console.log($scope.password);
    $scope.github = new Github({
      username: $scope.username,
      password: $scope.password,
      auth: "basic"
    });
  }
});
```

I have the console.log calls to be sure it's firing and it is.  However the $scope.github line doesn't seem to run.  I'm checking the console and network logs (chrome developer tools) and i'm expecting to see an https://api.github.com/{someotherstring} request but nothing fires off.  I know that the github code can work as i've run it in a non angular application.  So my question is what am I missing?

any help would be greatly appreciated.  Hopefully I've provided enough information for someone to go on.

Thanks in advance

bob

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form name="myForm" ng-controller="AuthCtrl" class="form-horizontal css-form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="enter username" required/><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.username.required">Required!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="password" placeholder="enter password" required/><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.pwd.required">Required!</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button ng-click="auth()">Login</button>
        </form>        
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is dependant upon the following libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/base64.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/github.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Provide your html view code.

Comment: You probably need to inject Github into your controller.

Comment: @Chandermani - code added above

Comment: @ZackArgyle - could you expand on this?

Comment: Yeah. Typically when you use an outside library from within a module like the controller, you have to inject the instance into the controller function. Something like app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, Github)...

Comment: Thanks @ZackArgyle I really appreciate the help.  I did as you said, however i'm now getting 
Error: Unknown provider: GithubProvider <- Github

I really new to angularjs so please excuse the ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

So looks like it was actually working.

i added

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.username = '';
$scope.password = '';
$scope.success = false;
$scope.auth = function() {
  console.log($scope.username);
  console.log($scope.password);
  $scope.github = new Github({
    username: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password,
    auth: "basic"
  });

  $scope.user = $scope.github.getUser();
  $scope.user.repos(function(err, repos) {
    $scope.err = err;
    $scope.repos = repos;
    if($scope.err != null)
    {
      console.log($scope.err);
    }else
    {
      console.log($scope.repos);
      $scope.success = true;
    }
  });

}
```

});

And it retrieved the repos when logged in.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Accept your answer if you solve it using this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**[angular-github-activity](http://gigablox.github.io/angular-github-activity)** can serve as an example to get your auth up and running.

From **[the docs](https://github.com/gigablox/angular-github-activity#data)**:

```
GithubActivityService.events({
  user:'gigablox',
  params:{

    //Github API supports CORS as well. (http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing)
    callback:'JSON_CALLBACK', 

    /*
    Github API rate limits to (60 requests per hour) for anonymous requests. (http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing)

    If you need more (5000 requests per hour) you can generate a "scope-less" (access_token) for your app and is safe for client side code:

    1. First register a new app by following:
        --> https://github.com/settings/applications
        --> "Developer Applications"
        --> "Register new application"
    2. Register a "scope-less" (access_token) via cURL call using that <client_id> and <client_secret> you just made.
        # curl -X PUT -H "application/json" -d
          '{"client_secret":"<client_secret>","scopes":[],"note":"no scope public access"}'
          https://api.github.com/authorizations/clients/<client_id>
          -u <username>
    3. Your response shoud look something like this and generate a scope-less (token):
        {
          "id": 1234567,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations/1234567",
          "app": {
            "name": "Angular Github Activity",
            "url": "http://gigablox.github.io/angular-github-activity/",
            "client_id": "123456712345671234567"
          },
          "token": "76841d7b319dc8bb2c731365d38b74b25ab00126", //<-- This is what you want
          "note": "no scope public access",
          "note_url": null,
          "created_at": "2013-10-06T21:06:18Z",
          "updated_at": "2013-10-06T21:06:18Z",
          "scopes": []
        }
    */

    access_token:'76841d7b319dc8bb2c731365d38b74b25ab00126' //<-- Put that bad boy right here.
  }
}).get().$promise.then(function(events){
  $scope.events = events.data;
});
```